# Automate GUI interaction against directory of files

Tags: automation, windows-server, macros

I use a program called [OkMap](http://www.okmap.org/) which I use to generate Garmin Custom Map KMZ files from GeoTiffs. Every now and then I need to process a bunch of updated files, last time it was 80.

The task is pretty repetitive and I'd like to automate it. OkMap itself doesn't provide a command line interface so I'm wondering if anyone can recommend a some automation / macro software that can record and repeat the repetitive steps against each file within a directory.

The task I want to automate in OkMap can be found under the "Utilities" > "Map tiling / Garmin custom maps" menu item.

The software needs to run on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Here are four possible solutions, all of these should run on Windows Server 2012 R2

1.) **[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)** (Free)
[image: AutoHotKey Logo]
Fast scriptable desktop automation with hotkeys
Creating your own apps and macros has never been easier
This requires some coding (It's not too complicated)

2.) **[Pulover’s Macro Creator](https://www.macrocreator.com/)** (Free)
[image: Pulover's Macro Creator Interface]
A Free Automation Tool and Script Generator. It is based on AutoHotkey language and provides users with multiple automation functions, as well as a **built-in recorder**.

3.) **[Macro Recorder by JitBit](https://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/)** (Plans start at $39)
[image: Macro Recorder's Interface]
Macro Recorder - the best macro program for Windows. Not just a keyboard and mouse recorder but a powerful automation tool that converts macros to EXE files and more.

4.) **[AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)** (Free)
[image: AutoIt Script Editor]
AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or reliable with other languages.